# Sending email using Perl using sendmail

Tags: perl, email

I am following the example from [this website](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_sending_email.htm) to send an email using Perl. The code looks like so:

```
my $hostname = `hostname`;
my $this_day = `date`;
my $email = "i.h4d35\@gmail.com";
my $to = "$email";
my $from = "admin\@$hostname";
my $subject = "SCHEDULE COMPLETE - $this_day";
my $message = "Student schedule for today, completed for the following students: \n\n$names\n\nHave a nice day...";
open(MAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");
print MAIL "To: $to\n";
print MAIL "From: $from\n";
print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n\n";
print MAIL $message;
close(MAIL);
```

The mail gets sent but the subject appears in the body of the mail and the email has no subject. How do I fix this?

PS: Have not gotten around to using `MIME::Lite` yet as I am still learning this.

Comment: can't reproduce your issue. works fine for me.

Comment: That's not a very good Perl tutorial. You would be better off looking at the tutorials at http://learn.perl.org/ or http://perl-tutorial.org/.

Comment: Email sending is same as doing HTTP request. You need to have CRLF after every row.
https://ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using examples from websites is a bad idea.

Especially any website that instructs you to craft and send low-level formats directly.

You should not implement any of the following formats manually:

- Email
- HTML
- CSV
- IRC Protocol
- etc

Which lots of websites unhelpfully detail how to do, when they should simply be telling you how to achieve these tasks with a module.

Here is a much more simple approach, using Email::Sender and Email::Simple, both quality pieces of software written by somebody who deals with Email for a living.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $hostname = `hostname`;
my $this_day = `date`;

use Email::Simple;
use Email::Simple::Creator;
use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);

my $email = Email::Simple->create(
 header => [
       From => "admin\@$hostname",
       To => "i.h4d35\@gmail.com",
       Subject => "SCHEDULE COMPLETE - $this_day",
 ],
 body => "Student schedule for today, completed for the following students: \n\n$names\n\nHave a nice day..."
);
sendmail($email);
```

Comment: "Using examples from websites is a bad idea."  Even http://stackoverflow.com ? ;)

Comment: @Kenosis Often, yes, even stackoverflow, there's quite a few answers here that write Perl like its 1989 still. ;) But generally, the problem is 2-fold, 1: "Literature gets old fast" and 2: "Learning from people who learn from old literature is old knowledge". 

Even my answers, which I strive to make as recent as possible, will be outdated in a few years.

Comment: I actually do know what you mean, but was only (ironically) thinking of your excellent response to the OP's question.  I absolutely (and quite embarrassingly) dropped the ball in an erroneous response to a `split` question the other day--even though I've been using it for close to 20 years.  It's not just the answers that are getting old...

Comment: Looking at Email::Sender::Transport::Sendmail, I must admit they do exactly what topic starter does - they open a pipe to sendmail, see sub _sendmail_pipe. For such a simple email I personally would stick to open(MAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");

Comment: Here is the problem with this answer. It adds dependencies on the Email::Simple Perl modules which may or may not be present where the script is going to be executed. OTOH, you can probably safely assume that unix sendmail command is going to be there.

Comment: @lano1106 you can safely assume unix sendmail is there, but I'm going to be reasonably safe in assuming how you assemble an email to pass to it will be prone to all kinds of security risks. eg: If you allow user-specified values for "To",  and don't sanitize it right, you've basically given them veto power to add whatever headers they like, including the ability to convert your mail service into a spam relay.

Answer (score 4):

The output of `hostname` includes a newline, so `$from` contains a newline, so the `Subject:` line appears after a pair of newlines, so it’s interpreted as being in the message body. Easy to fix:

```
chomp($hostname);
```

You may find a similar issue with `date`.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove all newlines from fields which go into mail header.

```
tr|\r\n||d for $to, $from, $subject;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use MIME::Lite;

my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
       From    => 'you@your-server.com',
       To      => 'somerandom@gmail.com',
       Type    => 'text/plain',
       Subject => 'your subject',
       Data    => 'your message',
);

$msg->send;
```

Comment: MIME::Lite is not recommended by its current maintainer. http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/MIME-Lite-3.030/lib/MIME/Lite.pm

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me hope its helpful

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$to = 'sendmailtouser@company.com';
$from = 'fromuser@company.com';
$subject = 'Party!!!';
$message = 'Details of party';

open(MAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");

# Email Header
print MAIL "To: $to\n";
print MAIL "From: $from\n";
print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n\n";
# Email Body
print MAIL $message;

close(MAIL);
print "Email Sent Successfully\n";
```